# Using Microsoft.Toolkit.Parsers.RssParser only in my project

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I am currently building samples for [Blazor](http://blazor.net) . I am building a RSS Reader in Blazor. I looked at Microsoft.Toolkit.Parsers nuget package. The package has a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json. But Blazor does not yet support Newtonsoft.Json. I looked into the code of RssParser and it no where uses Newtonsoft.Json. 
My question is - can i just use the source code of RssParser in my Blazor Project. I want to just copy the RssParser related classes into my project and use it. 
Is it permissible to do this ? I am looking for some guidelines/direction here ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You are free to use the source code as needed.

Related: If you notice the project is referencing something it shouldn't please log an issue to the repo directly. We'll look into if the parser project actually uses json.net and if not remove it for the next version.

UPDATE: I have submitted a [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/pull/2289) that removes Json.Net from the library

Comment: Hi Shawn,Thanks a ton for the answer. And thanks for the PR :) ... appreciate it. I was able to copy just the RSS bits and it works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime someone comes with a better answer check this xml based RSS parser.
https://rollerweblogger.org/roller/entry/parsing_rss_with_net

(I guess, it should work with Blazor).

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thanks for the link. Do have a look at the RssParser available in UWP Community toolkit. Personally i like the way it has been designed.

Comment: Yes,  will take a look and also we are just starting with Blazor for an early prototype app.   Will share the experience,  issues as encountered. Thanks